# How to show div content and hide others when button is clicked - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**I want to show a particular div only when a particular button is clicked.** Like if button with id #newLD is clicked then the only div with id #createLD should be displayed and other divs should remain hidden. I need the same functionality for all three buttons I created.

*P.S - I checked other solutions on Stackoverflow but code isn't working for me. They make it look too complicated. Please help and suggest the easiest method that can be understood by beginners.*

```css
button {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border: 0 solid;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<div id="button-container">
    <button id="newLD" class="myButton">Logo</button>
    <button id="newVC" class="myButton">Visiting Card</button>
    <button id="newFD" class="myButton">Flyer Design</button>
</div>


    <div id="createLD" style="display: none">
        <p>Here is the lofo design div</p>
    </div>

    <div id="createVC" style="display: none">
        <p>Here is the visitng card design div</p>
    </div>

    <div id="createFD" style="display: none">
        <p>Here is the flyer design design div</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this solution but this isn't working. He used so many div that is confusing me [link](https://codepen.io/sagar_arora/pen/BRBopY)

Comment: Which solution?

Comment: The solution you've linked to is probably the simplest you'll get - add a `data-show` with the selector to what you want to show.  Parsing IDs is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can try matching the respective elements with [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [Attribute Ends With Selector [name$="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```js
$('.myButton').click(function(){
  $('div[id^=create]').hide(); //hide all
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); //get the id of the clicked button
  var end = id.slice(-2);      //get last 2 character (LD/VC/FD) from id
  $(`div[id$=${end}]`).show(); //match the div with id ends with the character and show
});
```

```css
button {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  border: 0 solid;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button-container">
  <button id="newLD" class="myButton">Logo</button>
  <button id="newVC" class="myButton">Visiting Card</button>
  <button id="newFD" class="myButton">Flyer Design</button>
</div>


<div id="createLD" style="display: none">
  <p>Here is the lofo design div</p>
</div>

<div id="createVC" style="display: none">
  <p>Here is the visitng card design div</p>
</div>

<div id="createFD" style="display: none">
  <p>Here is the flyer design design div</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: Get the id of the button that is clicked, hide all divs with an id starting with "create" and show only the div that has the corresponding id.

```js
$(".myButton").on("click", function() {
  let id = $(this).attr("id");
  id = id.substr(3);
  $("div[id^='create']").hide();
  $("div[id='create" + id + "']").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button-container">
  <button id="newLD" class="myButton">Logo</button>
  <button id="newVC" class="myButton">Visiting Card</button>
  <button id="newFD" class="myButton">Flyer Design</button>
</div>


<div id="createLD" style="display: none">
  <p>Here is the lofo design div</p>
</div>

<div id="createVC" style="display: none">
  <p>Here is the visitng card design div</p>
</div>

<div id="createFD" style="display: none">
  <p>Here is the flyer design design div</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".myButton").on("click", function() {
  let id = $(this).attr("id");

if(id=='newLD'){
  $('createLD').show()
$('createVC').hide()
$('createFD').hide()
}
else if(id=='newVC'){
  $('createVC').show()
$('createLD').hide()
$('createFD').hide()
}
else if(id=='newFD'){
  $('createFD').show()
$('createVC').hide()
$('createLD').hide()
}
});
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button-container">
  <button id="newLD" class="myButton">Logo</button>
  <button id="newVC" class="myButton">Visiting Card</button>
  <button id="newFD" class="myButton">Flyer Design</button>
</div>


<div id="createLD" style="display: none">
  <p>Here is the lofo design div</p>
</div>

<div id="createVC" style="display: none">
  <p>Here is the visitng card design div</p>
</div>

<div id="createFD" style="display: none">
  <p>Here is the flyer design design div</p>
</div>
```